# while saving data from grid view getting object reference error in windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

i am working on vb.net windows form application ,,i have a data grid

[image]

I have two tables `1->CompanyMaster_tbl` in this having Two fields . `Cid and CompanyName`,

> Cid is the primary key of this table

2->`DepartmentMaster_tbl` in this having 4 fields. `dtid,dtname,dtphon,dtmail,Cid`.

> dtid is the primary key,and Cid is the foreign key

while clicking save button i want save the data in both table.
in one company i want to save multiple departments. my **Cid** and **dtid** are autoincriment,,i mean Identity specication i set as true..in save button i given code like this,,

```
 Dim sqlInsertT1 As String = ""
 Dim sqlInsertT2 As String = ""
 Dim CompanyMaster_tbl As DataTable = Nothing
 Dim DepartmentMaster_tbl As DataTable = Nothing

 For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows
   For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
     If gv.Rows(i).Cells("cmpny").Value <> "" Then
       sqlInsertT1 &= "Insert Into CompanyMaster_tbl(CompanyName) Values ('" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("cmpny").Value & "');"
       Exetransaction(sqlInsertT1)
     End If
     Ccid = RecordID("Cid", "CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", gv.Rows(i).Cells("cmpny").Value)
   Next

   For Each DepartmentMaster_row As DataRow In DepartmentMaster_tbl.Select(Ccid)
     For j As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
       sqlInsertT2 &= "Insert Into DepartmentMaster_tbl(dtname,dtphone,dtEmail,Cid) Values ('" & gv.Rows(j).Cells("Dpmnt").Value & "','" & gv.Rows(j).Cells("dtphon").Value & "','" & gv.Rows(j).Cells("mail").Value & "'," & Ccid & ");"
       Exetransaction(sqlInsertT2)
     Next
   Next
 Next
```

but  this logic is not enough for saving this data,,
in save button if i am editing  something in grid view ,,i want to update that value in particular table
in the below line  i am getting error like this:**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

> For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows

so how i can resolve this issue? i try after filling my company master table,,but then also i am getting same error

Comment: Initially i would suggest you to use transaction. After insert you can select scope_identity in order to get the just inserted id.

Comment: What's the relationship between the datatables and the datagridview? Are they bound? If not, how is the datagridview populated?

Comment: in load event i written some coding for populating the data grid view,,

Comment: i am taking each value then i am passing to datagridview, like this: Dim row0 As String() = {cmpname, dtname, dtphon, dtmail}
            gv.Rows.Add(row0)

Answer (score 2):

In your posted code, you have assigned a value of `Nothing` to `CompanyMaster_tbl` just before you try to access it. That's why you're getting the exception.

```
Dim CompanyMaster_tbl As DataTable = Nothing

For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows
```

The exception is thrown when you try to access the `Rows` property of the null object.

Comment: instead of nothing i given my table name ..then also i am getting error

Comment: fill/get/populate `CompanyMaster_tbl` before you try to iterate it

Comment: i filled CompanyMaster_tbl  manually,,then i try to iterate ..but getting same error